# QGIS library to OSGEO library codes

Tags: qgis, osgeo

is there any way to convert the scripts which is produced in QGIS as python scripts from processing modeler to codes using osgeo library codes?

i want some codes that can be used in QGIS algorithm in OSGEO library

Comment: I assume you mean GDAL/OGR, not OSGEO. There are many [projects](https://www.osgeo.org/projects) under the OSGEO umbrella.  And no, you would need to port your script manually.